# FQL facebook return data too slow

Tags: facebook, performance, facebook-fql

it take about 6898 ms to load data.

SELECT thumbnail_link, description, link, embed_html, title, created_time, owner, vid FROM video WHERE owner = 477934732233267 OR owner = 350544878418504 OR owner = 534680473216081 OR owner = 539004829516696 OR owner = 663513950371958 OR owner = 426622064081752 OR owner = 289025427915372 OR owner = 382955545140493 ORDER BY created_time DESC LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0

Comment: I suggest you don't do that way, you should request the API per owner perspective. The reasons have two, firstly you can't do pagination. Secondly your data response is too big and  easily timeout and throw "Request failed" error.

Answer (score 0):

You could speed this up a little bit by using an IN-list instead of ORs, but still over 5 secs:

```
SELECT thumbnail_link, description, link, embed_html, title, created_time, owner, vid FROM video WHERE owner in (477934732233267, 350544878418504, 534680473216081, 539004829516696, 663513950371958, 426622064081752, 289025427915372, 382955545140493) ORDER BY created_time DESC LIMIT 20
```

I suspected the sort to be time-consuming, but removing the ORDER BY doesn't have a big impact. So, I think you'll have to live with the response times.